# Date Format - US wanted Germany is default Excel

Tags: excel, date, vba

I need to develop a template for world wide use, and the date format needs to be validated and shown as the US-Format. The problem is, i am working in germany and I tried this:

[image: Date Format]

But I want it to be validated as the US-Format with MM/DD/YYYY but when entering it as that format, I get Invalid Date, but I need the values to be validated for MM/DD/YYYY does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Are you using VBA at all? Or would you be willing to use VBA to do that? Easiest way would be to change your regional settings to US, btw.

Comment: @Nacorid I need to use VBA only, the problem is, if I change my Settings that is fine, but if somebody in France uses the same template the testing would be messed up again since in france it is again DD/MM/YYYY and not MM/DD/YYYY and I can not make the whole company change their regional settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Data Validation, you can loop in VBA through your dates and format them accordingly, then you can also prompt the user if any of them dates are entered incorrectly, such as below:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A

For i = 1 To LastRow
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not IsDate(ws.Cells(i, 1)) Then MsgBox "Incorrect date on row " & i
    'if not date then prompt user
    ws.Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
    'format as text

    ws.Cells(i, 1) = Format(Month(ws.Cells(i, 1)), "00") & "/" & Format(Day(ws.Cells(i, 1)), "00") & "/" & Format(Year(ws.Cells(i, 1)), "0000")
    'format as US Date
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: that, does not solve the problem, when the date is entered in the dd/mm/yyyy format, since the CDate() in Germany won't throw an error for 31/03/2018

Comment: @Patrick.H it won't throw an error but it will format the date as 03/31/2018, I thought that was what you wanted?

Comment: well the problem is out of that excel it will be uploaded into a database, so the value really needs to be that way not only the format, sorry if I was unclear

Comment: @Patrick.H I've updated my answer, it should work for you now, as the code will not only format as Text, but then it will write the Dates as MM/DD/YYYY US format, this way you should be able to upload into your database in the specified format.